# Using asp.net validation controls through code behind

Tags: asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator, validationsummary

I am trying to validate a textbox using RequiredFieldValidator and display error message in ValidationSummary through code behind, but I am not able to do that.
My code goes here

```
        if (txtUsrName.Text.Length == 0 || txtUsrAge.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            RequiredFieldValidator req = new RequiredFieldValidator();
            req.ID = "Required";
            req.ControlToValidate = txtUsrName.ID;                                
            req.IsValid = false;
            req.Visible = true;
            req.Enabled = true;                               
            req.ValidationGroup = "ValidationGroup";
            req.ErrorMessage = "Thease are required fields";
            req.InitialValue = "";
            req.Text = "*";

            ValidationSummary valsum = new ValidationSummary();
            ValidationSummaryDisplayMode mode = new ValidationSummaryDisplayMode();
            valsum.ID = "validatesummury";                
            valsum.HeaderText = "please correct the following errors";                
            valsum.DisplayMode = mode;
            valsum.ShowSummary = true;
            valsum.ValidationGroup = "ValidationGroup";
            valsum.Visible = true;                
        }
```

Please help me with this

Comment: You need to recreate the elements on pre-init again.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `Page.Validate() OR Page.Validate("YOUR_VALIDATION_GROUP")` and then check `Page.IsValid` to check if all validators are valid, and to special validator also you can use `YOUR_RequiredFieldValidator.IsValid` `'YOUR_RequiredFieldValidator' is one attached to your textbox control`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar question that may provide insight for you: [Unobtrusive Validation in Webforms using Data Annotations](http://forums.asp.net/t/1933372.aspx).  Data Annotations provide ways to check the length, minimum/maximum value, etc of class properties.